# scikit-learn not showing up on Location

Tags: python, macos, scikit-learn, spyder

So, I use Spyder for running my codes. Recently I had to use `scikit-learn`, which doesn't come with Spyder. So what I did was:

1. `pip install scikit-learn` (on terminal)
2. `python -m pip show scikit-learn` (on terminal)
   which showed me the Location [[terminal snapshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5skPG.png)
3. when I go to said Location, `scikit-learn` is nowhere to be found, hence I can't copy it into Spyder files. [[terminal snapshot]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkle9.png)

I have tried to copy it with:
`scp -r /Users/Keni/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scikit-learn /Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.9`
but of course I get No such file or directory.

How is it possible that it shows the location, but once I access the location, it is not there?
I've tried uninstalling it, re-installing it, forced no binary installation. I think IT IS installed, every time I try to pip install it I get Requirement already satisfied. I don't know what to do.

Comment: In `spyder`, what happens if you try `!pip install scikit-learn`?

Comment: ... from the `ipython` console.  How did you install `spyder`?

Comment: I can't use the terminal en Spyder bc I don't have pip installed and every time I try to install it I get a fatal error :(, so I gave up and been using this to go around it.

Comment: Did you use `conda` to install `spyder`?

Comment: No, I downloaded it directly from https://www.spyder-ide.org/

Comment: In the `ipython` console, what's the output of `!echo $PATH`?

Comment: These resources look helpful. [Q: How do I install Python packages to use within Spyder if I downloaded Spyder from the standalone installers?](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-packages-installer)  [YouTube:  Spyder FAQ: How do I use additional packages if I downloaded Spyder from the standalone installers?](https://youtu.be/i7Njb3xO4Fw)

Comment: FYI, IDK how your copying files around works, but `scikit-learn` lives in `sklearn`.  It's one of those packages that has a name different to its module. :-/